# String offset inside a function

Tags: c, string, printf, puts

Recently I stumbled upon this strange code :

```
main(){
char c[] = "STRING";
puts("AKSHAY"+2);
printf("%s",c+2);
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
SHAY
RING
```

Can someone please explain how this offset in string works.

Also when I tried this snippet of code, I got a compilation error :

```
main(){
char c[] = "STRING"+2;
printf("%s",c);
}
```

ERROR :

```
Line 2: error: invalid initializer
```

Is it something to do with pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your following code

```
main(){
char c[] = "STRING";
puts("AKSHAY"+2);
printf("%s",c+2);
}
```

What is happening here is that when you write

```
char c[]="STRING";
```

it means that `c` will be decayed into `pointer of type char` which holds the base address of "STRING" which is also of type `char *`.

so when you write

```
printf("%s",c+2);
```

`%s` specification means it will take the base address and print the characters upto NULL( or whitespace) .so `c+2` means `base address +2` so thats why it is printing

```
"RING"
```

on the other hand

```
puts("AKSHAY"+2);
```

puts also take the base address and print upto NULL ( INCLUDING WHITESPACES )

here type of "AKSHAY" is `char *` so adding `2` to it means changing base address to the letter `S`.so output is

```
SHAY
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just basic [pointer arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_and_C.2B.2B).

The type of a string literal is pointer to character, so you can add an offset to that pointer to get the "tail" of the string. The fact that this occurs "inside a function" doesn't matter.

Your test didn't work since you cannot initialize an array from an expression like that, it has to be a "bare" string literal.

Comment: Hmm okay I am kind of a newbie and all the words you said just went over my head.A simpler explanation would be appreciated :) Thank You for your answer though.